# Como evitar el parpadeo al redibujar constantemente figuras

Tags: c#

He estado trabajando en un editor de grafos para la universidad en el cual tengo que redibujar constantemente varias figuras, cuando lo hago pareciera que las figuras parpadean, estuve leyendo y encontre un control llamado BoubleBuffered pero no comprendi como utilizarlo ¿Alguien lo ha usado antes?¿o hay otras opciones para resolver este problema? dejo un pequeño fragmento de codigo como ejemplo de como dibujo.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            grafo = new Grafo();
            opcion = 0;
            g = CreateGraphics();
            bmp1 = new Bitmap(ClientSize.Width, ClientSize.Height);
            band = false;
            bandI = false;
            bandF = false;
    }

private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics gaux = CreateGraphics();

            gaux.Clear(BackColor);
            if (band)
            {
                bmp2 = (Bitmap)bmp1.Clone();
                g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp2);
                switch (opcion)
                {
                    case 2:
                        g.DrawLine(grafo.penA, grafo.BuscaInterseccion(nodoP.centro, p2), p2);
                        break;
                }
                gaux.DrawImage(bmp2, 0, 0);
                bmp2.Dispose();
                band = false;
            }
            else
            {
                g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp1);
                if (bandF)
                {
                    switch (opcion)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            g.FillEllipse(grafo.brushN, p1.X - grafo.radio, p1.Y - grafo.radio, grafo.radio * 2, grafo.radio * 2);
                            g.DrawEllipse(grafo.penN, p1.X - grafo.radio + (grafo.penN.Width /2), p1.Y - grafo.radio + (grafo.penN.Width / 2), grafo.radio * 2 - (grafo.penN.Width / 2), grafo.radio * 2 - (grafo.penN.Width / 2));
                            if (grafo.numN >= 28 || grafo.edoNom)
                                g.DrawString(nodoP.nombre.ToString(), grafo.font, grafo.brushF, p1.X - 6, p1.Y - 6);
                            else
                                g.DrawString(((char)(nodoP.nombre + 64)).ToString(), grafo.font, grafo.brushF, p1.X - 6, p1.Y - 6);
                        break;

                        case 2:
                            g.DrawLine(grafo.penA, grafo.BuscaInterseccion(nodoP.centro, nodoAux.centro), grafo.BuscaInterseccion(nodoAux.centro, nodoP.centro));
                        break;
                    }
                    bandF = false;
                }

                if(bandI)
                {
                    g.Clear(BackColor);
                    grafo.ImprimirGrafo(g);
                    bandI = false;
                }

                if(opcion == 6 || opcion == 7)
                {
                    g.Clear(BackColor);
                    if (opcion == 7)
                    {
                        grafo.Clear();
                        grafo.numN = 1;
                        grafo.edoNom = false;
                    }
                }
                gaux.DrawImage(bmp1, 0, 0);
            }
            gaux.Dispose();
        }

private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            p1 = e.Location;
            textBox1.Text = p1.ToString();
            switch(opcion)
            {
                case 1:
                    nodoP = new NodoP(grafo.numN++, p1);
                    grafo.Add(nodoP);
                    band = false;
                    bandF = true;
                    if (grafo.numN == 28)
                    {
                        bandI = true;
                        grafo.edoNom = true;
                    }
                    else
                        bandI = false;
                    Invalidate();
                    break;

                case 2:
                    nodoP = grafo.BuscaNodo(p1);
                    if (nodoP != null)
                    {
                        band = true;
                        bandA = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        band = false;
                        bandI = false;
                    }
                    break;

                case 3:
                    nodoP = grafo.BuscaNodo(p1);
                    if (nodoP != null)
                        bandA = true;
                    else band = false;
                    break;

                case 8:
                    p1 = e.Location;
                break;

            }
        }



private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.Button.Equals(MouseButtons.Left) && opcion == 2 && bandA)
            {
                p2 = e.Location;
                band = true;
                Invalidate(false);
            }

            if (e.Button.Equals(MouseButtons.Left) && opcion == 3 && bandA)
            {
                band = false;
                bandF = false;
                bandI = true;
                nodoP.centro = e.Location;
                Invalidate();
            }
    }
```

El fragmento anterior ejemplifica en como (segun yo) maneje la paginacion, con g, gaux y los bmp para dibujar, gracias por su ayuda :)

Comment: En tu ejemplo faltan muchos datos. No sabemos que es `band`, `opcion`,etc...Te recomiendo que hagas un [mcve]  que ayudará a que alguien pueda ver tu problema y tratar de ayudarte.

Comment: @Pikoh no sientí que sea necesario, ya que el ejemplo es solo para hacer notar como uso los Graphics (g y gaux) y los bmp, gracias por el comentario de todas formas, escribire una version muy resumida del codigo (porque si pongo en donde modifico opcion y band seran muchisimas lineas) y lo editaré

Comment: la técnica de doble buffer es básicamente dibujar cosas en un lado (cosas que tardan en dibujarse) que sería el primer buffer (back buffer), y pintar en pantalla un segundo buffer (front buffer), este segundo buffer sólo se actualiza con lo que hay en el primer buffer cuando en el primer buffer no hay nadie dibujando. hay otra técnica llamada triple buffer donde se utiliza un buffer intermedio (o segundo back buffer) para tener un frame extra ya dibujado si el render final es muy rápido

Comment: No entiendo que dibujes con g, gaux. Entras en el evento Paint del formulario y estás dibujando en bitmaps. Luego haces sentencias como grafo.ImprimirGrafo(g); donde previamente haces  g.Clear(BackColor); No entiendo dónde está el código que dibuja en pantalla. Lo normal es que cuando entras en el evento Paint del formulario uses el objeto gráfico e.Graphics para dibujar. Veo todo el trabajo auxiliar de dibujo en bitmaps pero no veo el volcado a pantalla. Podrías aclarar este aspecto.